# Find and fill an input field with AutoHotKey

Tags: web-scraping, autohotkey, getelementbyid

A challenge to all you AutoHotKey masters:

Give us a function that will **Find and Move the Cursor** to an Input Field (E.g. LoginName) and, alternatively send input text.  For the old, lazy hackers like myself just fiddling with AHK, it would look like this:

```
FindFillField(*elementid*,*sendtext*,*alt-text*)
```

Where `elementid` is the HTML id for the field, e.g. USERNAME,
where `sendtext` is the text to fill and
where `alt-text` could be additional, specific text to help identify the fields.

Additional, *optional parameters* are always helpful to round out odd cases so let your imaginations run wild!

For old-timers like me, and for anyone, this would be a blessing in creating simple login macros.

Comment: These may be helpful: [Example of Navigating a Website](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/39048-example-of-navigating-a-website/) and [search a button on a web page and click on it?](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/122175-search-a-button-on-a-web-page-and-click-on-it/)

Answer (score 3):

You can always use the {TAB} option. Open the website and hit the TAB key until you reach the input field and count how many times you hit it. Then do 
Send {TAB ##}. I used the below to put in First name, middle name, last name, and 2 other id into a web form. The variables were entered into a GUI form that was created.

```
Send {TAB 41}
Send %firstn%
Send {TAB}
Send %middle%
Send {TAB}
Send %lastn%
Send {TAB}
Send %deas%
Send {TAB}
Send %npis%
Send {TAB 3}
Send {N}
Send {TAB 2}
Send {ENTER}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can send text to an input field with the following code:

```
wb.document.getElementById("login-username").value := "myUserName"
```

Where `wb` is the COM object, `login-username` is the ID of the input field, and `myUserName` is what you wish to input.

Insted of ID, you can also find the input field by name `getElementsByName(...)`, tag name `getElementsByTagName(...)` or class name `getElementsByClassName(...)`. I've found [this tutorial](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/47052-basic-webpage-controls-with-javascript-com-tutorial/) to be useful. Use Chrome or Firefox to find out how to identify the input field (rightclick and press "inspect element").

If you want to move the cursor to the input field, use

```
wb.document.getElementById("login-username").focus()
```

Here is a full example, using IE and the Stack Overflow login page:

```
; Create IE instance
wb := ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
wb.Visible := True
wb.Navigate("https://stackoverflow.com/users/login")
; Wait for page to load:
While wb.Busy or wb.ReadyState != 4
    Sleep, 100
; Press "Log in using Stack Exchange"
wb.document.getElementById("se-signup-legend").click()
While wb.Busy or wb.ReadyState != 4
    Sleep, 100
; EITHER focus on the input field:
wb.document.getElementsByName("email")[0].focus()
; OR send text directly to the field:
wb.document.getElementsByName("email")[0].value := "my@email.com"
```