# How can I focus and autofill a text field in Autohotkey?

Tags: web-scraping, autohotkey

I'm attempting to write a script to automatically fill a web-field with the current date using an AutoHotkey script. However, I'm not sure how to focus a specific field by its `name` or `id`.

My current hacky workaround is to use `Send, {Tab 84}` to scroll to the specific field, type the date with `Send, 6/28/2017`, and submit the field manually. While the script works most of the time, it's blatantly apparent there are better methods.

**How can I focus autofill specific text-field on a webpage using an AutoHotkey script?**

Comment: If the specific field doesn't change its position on the webpage, you can use the Click or the ControlClick command. A better choise would be ControlSend or ControlFocus, but I doubt that Autohotkey could recognize any edit control on a webpage.

Comment: Found a possible (unanswered) duplicate: [Find and fill an input field with AutoHotKey](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30102439/3357935)

Answer (score 0):

An IE COM object should do the trick, as long as you're comfortable navigating the DOM with some JS of your own.

Here's an example:

```
F3::
wb := ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application") ; Create a IE instance
wb.Visible := True
wb.Navigate("http://google.com")
Sleep, 5000
SendInput, This is test.{Enter}
Sleep, 5000
wb.document.getElementById("lst-ib").value := "This is another test."
wb.document.getElementById("_fZl").click()
return
```