# How can I execute Javascript methods with AutoHotkey?

Tags: javascript, browser, autohotkey

I am writing an AutoHotkey script to enter data into an Oracle PeopleSoft application. Rather than trying to locate specific elements on the page, I want to try execute JavaScript commands directly instead.

So instead of using a hardcoded `MouseClick, left, 205, 281` to click the "Add New Values" button, I want to directly run `submitAction_win0(document.win0,'#ICSwitchMode')`

I've tried entering commands directly into the address bar, but this doesn't seem to have any effect.

```
#k::
   jsCommand = javascript:submitAction_win0(document.win0,'#ICSwitchMode');
   Send, !d                  ; places cursor in URL field
   Send, %jsCommand%{Enter}  ; submit JS command (doesn't work)
Return
```

[According to this AHK thread](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/90130-is-there-any-way-to-execute-javascript-code-via-ahk/), it should be possible to accomplish this using a ScriptControl object, but I'm a bit unsure how to use them.

How can I execute JavaScript commands using AutoHotkey?

Comment: You'll only be able to call methods that are globally available that way.

Comment: What shows up in the JS console?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 `SCRIPT5007: The value of the property 'submitAction_win0' is null or undefined, not a Function object` 
 ZZ_KRONOS.ZZ_KRONELIG_DPT.GBL, line 1 character 1

Comment: There you go, `submitAction_win0` is not defined and therefore you can't call it.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I'm confused why it would work when pressing the button directly, but not when entered in the URL bar. The button element is defined as `<a class="PSHYPERLINK" tabindex="3" href="javascript:submitAction_win0(document.win0,'#ICSwitchMode');" &add="" a="" new="" value="" accesskey="A"><span><abbr class="PTUNDERLINE">A</abbr>dd a New Value</span></a>`

Comment: There are many reasons why it won't work. Are you actually entering the JavaScript code into the correct page? Did you wait for the page to finish loading before executing it via the address bar? Was `submitAction_win0` dynamically generated?

Comment: It's easy to automate internet explorer with Autohotkey see the following link for a good tutorial: https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/47052-basic-webpage-controls-with-javascript-com-tutorial/

Comment: @Oleg Can you post that comment to 
[Find and fill an input field with AutoHotKey](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30102439/3357935)?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro I can but don't know if I should... please do it yourself if you think mentioning that tutorial there will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Per an example I used in a previous question's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45936202/563231) for controlling IE, walking the DOM, etc:

```
F3::
wb := ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application") ; Create a IE instance
wb.Visible := True
wb.Navigate("http://google.com")
Sleep, 5000
SendInput, This is test.{Enter}
Sleep, 5000
wb.document.getElementById("lst-ib").value := "This is another test."
wb.document.getElementById("_fZl").click()
return
```